# Python Django migrate not picking up change from makemigrations

Tags: python, django

I added a new model to `models.py` corresponding to a new SQL table I need to create. I included a field, `Id`, which apparently it does not like, as `python manage.py migrate` said that it was a duplicate field (presumably an `Id` field is also being automatically added or something).

That's fine, so I removed that field from the model and re-ran `python manage.py makemigrations`, which correctly reported that the `Id` field was being removed. I think re-ran `python manage.py migrate`, but it still gives the same error of there being a duplicate `Id` field...

From `models.py`:

```
class TII(models.Model):
    Person_bnr_id = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    COURSE_IDENTIFICATION = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    Course_start = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    Course_end = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W01 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W02 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W03 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W04 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W05 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W06 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W07 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W08 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W09 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W10 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W11 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    TurnItIn_W12 = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
```

From `python manage.py migrate`:

```
(P27_D19) [root@mdbiawebappdev1 loeuk]# python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, studentprogress, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying studentprogress.0100_tii...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 59, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/schema.py", line 535, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/schema.py", line 584, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/srv/P27_D19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 537, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S21', "[42S21] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Id' in table 'studentprogress_tii' is specified more than once. (2705) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Here is the output of `showmigrations`:

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
studentprogress
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_delete_aa
 [X] 0003_advisor
 [X] 0004_student
 [X] 0005_delete_student
 [X] 0006_student
 [X] 0007_staff
 [X] 0008_remove_staff_mgrid
 [X] 0009_auto_20160505_0909
 [X] 0010_delete_generaluser
 [X] 0011_generaluser
 [X] 0012_remove_generaluser_institution
 [X] 0013_delete_generaluser
 [X] 0014_generaluser
 [X] 0015_delete_generaluser
 [X] 0016_generaluser
 [X] 0017_delete_student
 [X] 0018_delete_generaluser
 [X] 0019_generaluser
 [X] 0020_delete_generaluser
 [X] 0021_generaluser
 [X] 0022_student
 [X] 0023_delete_student
 [X] 0024_student
 [X] 0025_studenthold
 [X] 0026_studentsro
 [X] 0027_delete_studentsro
 [X] 0028_studentsro
 [X] 0029_delete_studentsro
 [X] 0030_studentprep
 [X] 0031_student_program_end_date
 [X] 0032_studentfirstmodule
 [X] 0033_studentpaymentdetail_studentpaymentsummary
 [X] 0034_auto_20160615_1243
 [X] 0035_delete_studentpaymentdetail
 [X] 0036_studentpaymentdetail
 [X] 0037_delete_studentpaymentdetail
 [X] 0038_studentpaymentdetail
 [X] 0039_auto_20160615_1310
 [X] 0040_delete_studentpaymentdetail
 [X] 0041_studentpaymentdetail
 [X] 0042_delete_studentpaymentdetail
 [X] 0043_studentpaymentdetail
 [X] 0044_delete_studentpaymentdetail
 [X] 0045_studentpaymentdetail
 [X] 0046_remove_studentpaymentdetail_effective_due_date
 [X] 0047_studentpaymentdetail_effective_due_date
 [X] 0048_auto_20160615_2307
 [X] 0049_auto_20160615_2309
 [X] 0050_studentsummary
 [X] 0051_delete_studentfirstmodule
 [X] 0052_studentfirstmodule
 [X] 0053_delete_studentfirstmodule
 [X] 0054_studentfirstmodule
 [X] 0055_delete_studentfirstmodule
 [X] 0056_studentfm_uol_studentfm_uor
 [X] 0057_delete_studentfm_uol
 [X] 0058_studentfm_uol
 [X] 0059_delete_studentsummary
 [X] 0060_studentsummary
 [X] 0061_advisorportfolio
 [X] 0062_delete_advisorportfolio
 [X] 0063_advisorportfolio
 [X] 0064_auto_20160712_1525
 [X] 0065_advisor_advisor_name
 [X] 0066_auto_20160713_1614
 [X] 0067_auto_20160713_1616
 [X] 0068_remove_advisor_institution
 [X] 0069_auto_20160713_1620
 [X] 0070_advisor_location
 [X] 0071_auto_20160713_1624
 [X] 0072_auto_20160715_1437
 [X] 0073_studentprep
 [X] 0074_moduleprogress_onboarding
 [X] 0075_auto_20160722_1422
 [X] 0076_studentmoduleprogress_studentonboarding
 [X] 0077_delete_studentmoduleprogress
 [X] 0078_studentmoduleprogress
 [X] 0079_delete_studentonboarding
 [X] 0080_studentonboarding
 [X] 0081_delete_studentonboarding
 [X] 0082_studentonboarding
 [X] 0083_delete_studentpaymentsummary
 [X] 0084_studentpaymentsummary
 [X] 0085_delete_studentpaymentsummary
 [X] 0086_studentpaymentsummary
 [X] 0087_delete_studentpaymentsummary
 [X] 0088_studentpaymentsummary
 [X] 0089_auto_20160905_1827
 [X] 0090_auto_20160905_1828
 [X] 0091_auto_20160905_1828
 [X] 0092_auto_20160905_1829
 [X] 0093_auto_20160905_1829
 [X] 0094_auto_20160906_1112
 [X] 0095_remove_student_referrer_email
 [X] 0096_auto_20160906_1114
 [X] 0097_student_referrer_first_name
 [X] 0098_student_referrer_last_name
 [X] 0099_student_referrer_email
 [ ] 0100_tii
 [ ] 0101_remove_tii_id
```

Comment: What is the output of `showmigrations`?

Comment: @RaphaëlGomès Great question, I will add that info now

Comment: Can you show us the `0100_tii` file?

Comment: @RaphaëlGomès Yea, sure. Adding that now.

Comment: That doesn't look like a migration file to me.

Comment: @RaphaëlGomès You are probably right. I've never done any of this before, I apologize. Can you explain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134792/discussion-between-raphael-gomes-and-hack-r).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `showmigrations` output shows that the `0100_tii` migration hasn't been applied yet.

```
[X] 0099_student_referrer_email
[ ] 0100_tii
[ ] 0101_remove_tii_id
```

Therefore I would delete both the `0100_tii` and `0101_remove_tii_id` files. Then you can rerun `makemigrations`. If all that `0100_tii` did was add the id field, then you might not need to run `makemigrations` until you make further changes to your model.

Comment: Awesome. Can you explain where to find those files so that I can delete them? This is my first time. Thanks!

Comment: That is my intuition as well, @Hack-R: please continue the discussion in chat with me (see the comments)

Comment: @RaphaëlGomès Sure, I will join the chat now. My boss was asking me something, sorry for the delay.

Comment: The app is `studentprogress`, so the migration files will be in `studentprogress/migrations/`.